# Concatenate two values with lambda expressions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like in `.ToDictionary()` to concatenate both category_code and category_name in to one *Value*. Right now I'm only sending category_name, but I want category_name + category_code. Is it possible?

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Party party = new Party();
    var list = repository.GetCategories()
        .Select(p => new { p.category_id, p.category_name, p.category_code })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .ToDictionary(m => m.category_id, m => m.category_name);

    party.categories = new SelectList(list, "Key", "Value", "SelectedValue");
    return View(party);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `.AsEnumerable()` can be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `.ToDictionary()`, `AsEnumerable`, `Select` with an anonymous object instead of something shorter:

```
var list = repository
    .GetCategories()
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem 
    { 
        Value = x.category_id.ToString(), 
        Text = x.category_name + x.category_code
    });
party.categories = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text", "SelectedValue");
```

Not to mention that this kind of stuff are better adapted to your mapping layer. For example if you are using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) your controller action could look like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var categories = repository.GetCategories();
    var categoriesViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Category>, IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>>(categories);
    var party = new PartyViewModel
    {
        Categories = categoriesViewModel
    }
    return View(party);
}
```

Comment: Because I want to give you a better rep? =)

Comment: If `repository.GetCategories()` returns an IQueryable then using .Select() is better than using something like AutoMapper - in regards to performance.

Comment: Also if `repository.GetCategories()` returns an IQueryable from an ORM, will `x.category_id.ToString()` work?

Comment: @Simon Bartlett, in regards to your comment about performance, AutoMapper wouldn't modify the way this collection is consumed, as you can see it works with `IEnumerables` so it would be the same. As far as the .ToString method is concerned it is indeed a good point. It might not be supported by the underlying implementation. In this case an anonymous object instead of `SelectListItem` (which requires a string value) would do just fine.

Comment: if `repository.GetCategories()` returns an IQueryable from an ORM and you use AutoMapper you'll load up entire entities from the DB, whereas .Select() will only load up what is required. Hence .Select() may be more performant. Again, it's all about the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .ToDictionary(m => m.category_id,  m => string.format("{0}{1}",m.category_name ,m.category_code));
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother using string.Format for something so simple.

Comment: @Simon it's easier to read I guess and it definitely doesn't hurt.

Comment: It's not any easier to read, and is slower than just concatenating the two strings. I have nothing against string.Format, but there is no need for it here.

Comment: standards enforce the use of string.format as much as possible my senior dev makes me do it all time. : @